# Value of type "catalogAttributeEntity()" cannot be converted to "catalogAttributeEntity"

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, magento, soap

Some background: I'm using the Magento Soap V2 wsdl webservice in Visual Studio 2015. I converted the webservice file into a dll and I am using that as a reference.

I'm having difficulty understanding the following error. The result of catalogProductAttributeListCompletedEventArgs is a catalogAttributeEntity() but when I click on the catalogAttributeEntity() in the Object Browser, it brings me to the same object catalogAttributeEntity.

```
Public Sub MageProdAttrListComplete(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As catalogProductAttributeListCompletedEventArgs) Handles msvc.catalogProductAttributeListCompleted
    Try
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Completed Successfully."
        Dim ResultProdAttrList As New catalogAttributeEntity
        ResultProdAttrList = e.Result
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + ResultProdAttrList.ToString

    Catch
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + e.Error.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

It is erroring at the fifth line with: Value of type "catalogAttributeEntity()" cannot be converted to "catalogAttributeEntity".

Any Ideas?

Comment: `catalogAttributeEntity()` is an *array* of `catalogAttributeEntity`. Also, the string concatenation operator in VB is `&`, not `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid errors like that by using [Option Infer On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) which will infer the type of a variable from what you are assigning to it. If you prefer to explicitly declare the types of variables, you can hover over the variable name and it will tell you what its type is. Some IDE add-ins will give you a simple right-click way of making it explicit.

```
Public Sub MageProdAttrListComplete(sender As System.Object, e As catalogProductAttributeListCompletedEventArgs) Handles msvc.catalogProductAttributeListCompleted
    Try
        Dim ResultProdAttrList = e.Result
        TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Completed successfully.")
        TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & ResultProdAttrList.ToString())

    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & e.Error.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I suspect that your "Completed succesfully." line is in the wrong place, and you might need a loop to output all the values of `catalogAttributeEntity`.